# Create Web Application from Swing Application

Tags: java, swing, video-conferencing

I already developed fully-fledged video chat application in Java with Swing but now my requirement is to make that application web based.

So where to I start? Is there any hint or any tool that convert my application into web based application?

Answer (score 2):

Launch the Swing GUI from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The only real alternative is to convert the frame to an applet.

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to say.. its just technology there is no option to make it web based?

Comment: What does 'web based' mean to you?  To me it means 'you can get it from a link'.  DYM you want this **embedded** in a web page?  To me that seems silly, especially for video conferencing.   That is the type of app. the user typically wants to resize (very hard to reliably do in a web page).  If you ***do*** want an embedded app., convert the free floating app. to an applet (as I already said).

Comment: <head-desk />  How many times do you want me to tell you?!?  The answer to your comment is in the answer, as well as my earlier comment!

Comment: hello i m creating webapplet for doing video conference so everywhere i search for this your comment is there.. that it is tricky or why you should try this.. it means you dont suggest to do this then can you have idea then what to use for doing this? kindly give me idea then what to use for this..

Comment: Can you reword that last comment so it makes the slightest bit of sense?

Comment: i said that i want to make one applet that is for webpage and using that i want to do video conference so i googled it for that but everytime when i got quotes from yourside its bit negative.. then what to apply for doing this? got it?

Comment: *"..got quotes from yourside its bit negative.."*  There is good reasons for that, which I usually explain at the time.  It is hard enough getting something like this working in a free-floating app. - concentrate on that first (that 'free floating app.' can be an applet launched using JWS - but get that sorted before trying to cram it in a web page (which adds a whole new level of complexity on top).  ***Got it?***

Comment: yeah got it.. now can you suggest me what to use for doing this?

Comment: 1. Convert the `JFrame` to a `JApplet`.  Search on it, there are various tutorials.  When you have a *specific* question, get back to us.  As it is, I will invest no more time on this question, which I consider is answered to the extent that it was asked.